# Meaning of summation over $j:(i,j)$?

Tags: calculus, summation, notation

What does the bound $j:(i,j)$ mean in this summation?
$$
\sum_{j:(i,j)\in E} I_{ij} \tag 1
$$
An example would be good.

I assume $E$ is a set with the elements $(i,j)$. So for instance, if $E=\{(1,2), (3,4), (5,6)\}$, what does the summation mean?

**Update:**

I have also seen the bound without "$j:$", so only $(i,j)\in E$ ([see Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulation_problem#Definition), I use $(i,j)$ instead).
$$
\sum_{(i,j)\in E} c(i,j) f(i,j) \tag 2
$$

Are there any differences between $(1)$ and $(2)$?

Comment: I would expect that the "$j:$" is unnecessary... and that it is easier written and understood as $\sum\limits_{(i,j)\in E}I_{ij}$ so with your example that would be $I_{1,2}+I_{3,4}+I_{5,6}$

Comment: Take all $j$ such that $j$ appears in a pair $(i,j) \in E$.

Comment: @Randall the reason why I dislike that is because $i$ still appears in $I_{ij}$.  It would make more sense to just take each pair $(i,j)$ appearing in $E$.  There is no rule that our indexing variable must exclusively be a number, we are perfectly allowed to have our indexing variable be an ordered pair instead.

Comment: I'm neither advocating nor defending it, just explaining/guessing what OP was handed.

Comment: @JMoravitz: $i$ may well be given here, say summing up just some probabilities in a row

Comment: If we were in fact merely looping over possible second entries, then with $E=\{(1,2),(2,2),(3,2),(4,4)\}$ what would be $\sum\limits_{j:(i,j)\in E}I_{i,j}$ be?  Would it have two terms in the sum or four terms in the sum?  If four terms, then my first comment stands and the "$j:$" is confusing and unnecessary.  If two terms, what would be the term corresponding to $j=2$?  What if there were not an easy way to compare, it being $(1,2),(a,2),(\sqrt{-1},2),(\heartsuit, 2)$ instead?

Comment: I guess $i$ is fixed, and you are considering the sum over all $j$ such that $(i,j)$ is in $E$. That is, $c_i = \sum_{j \text{ such that } (i,j)\in E} I_{ij}$